# Есть View, но Asp .net не видит его

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image: Ошибка]

[image: Сама View]

```
**ListCart.cshtml**

   
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ListCart";
}
<style>
    td, th {
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".updateCart").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var quantity = $(".quantity_" + $(this).attr("data-id")).val();
            console.log(quantity);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"@Url.Action("updateCart","Product")",
                data: {
                    id: $(this).attr("data-id"),
                    quantity:quantity
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ListCart","Product")';
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="list-cart">
    <table class="cart" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>STT</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        @{
            int STT = 0;
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.carts)
            {
                string txt_class = "quantity_" + item.Product.idProduct;
                STT++;
                int total = item.Product.Price * item.Quantity;
                <tr>
                    <td>@STT</td>
                    <td>@item.Product.Title</td>
                    <td><img src="~/images/@item.Product.UrlImage" width="100" height="100" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" class="@txt_class" value="@item.Quantity" /></td>
                    <td>@item.Product.Price</td>
                    <td>@total</td>
                    <td><a href="" data-id="@item.Product.idProduct" class="updateCart">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a asp-controller="Products" asp-action="deleteCart" asp-route-id="@item.Product.idProduct">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

```
**Products.ListCart**



   

    
  public IActionResult ListCart()
        {
            var cart = HttpContext.Session.GetString("cart");//get key cart
            if (cart != null)
            {
                List<CartItem> dataCart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartItem>>(cart);
                if (dataCart.Count > 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.carts = dataCart;
                    return View();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавьте в первой строке представления (View) директиву @model и укажите в ней ссылку на вашу Model или может быть ViewModel.  И еще создайте View для метода, наведя на него курсором и через правую кнопку мыши выберете создание представления, что бы в решении автоматически прописывалась связь этого метода контроллера со своим представлением.  Далее просто скопируйте весь код из уже созданного представления в новое представление.  Смотрите на [Метаните](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/3.1.php) или на [видео](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm_HvURobtaz8GrLaI-iQhhc)